# Probability of hidden outcome given partial information

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

I'm trying to reason about the probability of a random outcome that can't be measured based on the existence of other random outcomes that can be measured (silent vs detected data corruption, for example). I boiled down the problem to this abstraction:

***Suppose I roll a fair 20-sided die an unknown amount of times, and I truthfully reveal I rolled 11-20 five times. What's the probability I never rolled a 1?***

My intuition tells me to break the problem down and sum the probabilities:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(A|r=n+5)P(r=n+5)$$

i.e. If I rolled $n+5$ times and $5$ times were 11-20, the number of outcomes where I don't roll a 1 is $9^n*10^5*{n+5\choose 5}$, and the number of outcomes where I roll $n+5$ times and $5$ times are 11-20 is $10^n*10^5*{n+5\choose 5}$, which produces a probability of $(\frac9{10})^n$ that I don't roll a 1 given that I rolled $5$ 11-20s... But I can't simply sum this from $n=0\to\infty$ (which produces $10$ as the answer) because it's missing a multiplicand—*the probability that I rolled $n+5$ times*. That metric doesn't make sense to me as an independent variable, so this is clearly the wrong approach, but I can't think of a better one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $~k \in \{5,6,7,\cdots\},~$ let:

- $~f(k)~$ denote the probability that you rolled 11-20 exactly $~5~$ times out of the $~k~$ dice rolls.
- Let $~W~$ denote $~\displaystyle \sum_{k=5}^\infty f(k).$
- Let $~g(k)~$ denote the probability of not rolling a 1 in any of the $~k~$ dice rolls, given that you rolled 11-20 exactly $~5~$ times [e.g. $~g(5) = 1~$].

Then, the probability that you never rolled a $~1~$ is

$$\sum_{k=5}^\infty \left[ ~\frac{f(k)}{W} \times g(k) ~\right]. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, the fraction $~\frac{f(k)}{W}~$ represents **normalizing** $~f(k).~$  That is, the fraction represents the **relative** probability that there were exactly $~k~$ dice rolls.

So, the problem reduces to :

- Crafting the formula for $~f(k)$
- Computing $~W.$
- Crafting the formula for $~g(k).$

---

$$f(k) = \frac{\binom{k}{5}}{2^k}.$$

$$W = \frac{\binom{5}{5}}{2^5} + \frac{\binom{6}{5}}{2^6} + \frac{\binom{7}{5}}{2^7} + \cdots. \tag2 $$

Personally, while I suspect that there is a closed form expression for $~W,~$ I don't know how to obtain it.

Notice that for $~k \geq 6,~$

$$\frac{\binom{k+1}{5}}{2^{k+1}} \div \frac{\binom{k}{5}}{2^k} = \frac{k+1}{2(k-5)}.$$

So, by the [Ratio Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), $~W~$ will be finite.

$$g(k) = \left[\frac{9}{10}\right]^{k-5}. \tag3 $$

In (3) above, you know that exactly $~(k-5)~$ dice rolls were in the range 1 through 10.  The probability of an individual dice roll, from these $~(k-5)~$ dice rolls, not being $~1~$ is $~\displaystyle \frac{9}{10}.$

Comment: Thanks! I note [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5B%5C%2840%29%5C%2840%29n%2Bk%5C%2841%29+choose+k%5C%2841%29*Power%5Bp%2Ck%5DPower%5B%5C%2840%291-p%5C%2841%29%2Cn%5D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D) suggests *W* converges to 1/p. I vaguely recall deriving a closed form for a series like that using methods similar to geometric series, so I'm sure it's doable, but it's been many years.

Comment: If I've followed right, (1) reduces to [(p/(p+q))^(k+1)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BDivide%5B%5C%2840%29%5C%2840%29n%2Bk%5C%2841%29+choose+k%5C%2841%29*Power%5Bp%2Ck%5DPower%5B%5C%2840%291-p%5C%2841%29%2Cn%5D%2CSum%5B%5C%2840%29%5C%2840%29r%2Bk%5C%2841%29+choose+k%5C%2841%29*Power%5Bp%2Ck%5DPower%5B%5C%2840%291-p%5C%2841%29%2Cr%5D%2C%7Br%2C0%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D%5DPower%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1-p-q%2C1-p%5D%5C%2841%29%2Cn%5D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D), p=prob. of the announced rolls (11-20, so 1/2) and q=the failure (1, so 1/20), k=number of announced rolls (5).